# Text based noughts and crosses

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

I am a beginner in Java and trying to practice. I want to write a basic text based noughts and crosses game in java without any GUI. I want to test if it works by writing unit tests to check if they pass. I don't want any answers but just want guidance on how to go about doing this. This is what I have decided so far:

1. Have the following classes: `GameTest`, `Game`, `Board` and `Player` (have two instances of this)
2. Use an array for the board.

I would appreciate if anyone would have any suggestions on how i could improve or ideas on how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: That seems a reasonable start; what have you got so far?

Comment: more or less just the idea tbh. I've created the basic classes but am unsure of inititalising anything in the class. Because I may need to pass in a parameter when i create an instance of that class e.g. board in the Game class. So not very sure how to go about doing it. An example to get started would be appreciated please

Comment: Create a ctor that takes a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

it would probably go something like this:

1. a player should be 'x' or 'o' (or 0/1)
2. a board is a 1-d array(0..8) or 2d(3x3) array of int or char (0,1,2) or ('_','x','o')
3. methods:

   - switchTurn()
   - currentTurn() (return 'x'/'o')
   - playMove(player, cell) - cell can be a single integer (0..8) or 2d (0..2,0..2)
   - validMove() returns true
   - isWinner(player)
   - isDraw() (not valid moves)

this should give you a rough idea

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When you say a player should be 'x' or 'o', Does that mean i have to create two players classes like playerX and playerO? Or if I just have one class called Player, How would I pass in the value of X or O to each player? your help is much appreciated.... Also I assume these methods would go in the Player class and be called from the Game class?

Comment: it's really up to you. you can have a player as a class, with a "type" field that is x/o. you can put the switchTurn/currentTurn in Game class, validMove, isWinner, isDraw in board class, and playMove(board, cell) in player class for example. really up to you